# How can I get to dim everything except for the sourceView when presenting UIPopoverViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopovercontroller

I am developing a chat application similar to WhatsApp. When the user long presses a message a popover with options is presented. I want to dim everything in the background except for the popover and the sourceView of the popover. Like this: [image]

I tried this but all of the background gets dimmed:

```c
- (void)prepareForPopoverPresentation:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {
    [[popoverPresentationController containerView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.72]];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javad

You can add blank in full screen in the presenting view. Set black background color and alpha 0.5 which will create dim effect.

Thank you

Comment: Would that not dim everything, including the sourceView?

Comment: Yes, as the blank view is independent to the source view

Comment: All right, but I would like to keep the source view as is, i.e. not dimmed, only the surroundings of it, see the picture please.

Comment: I believe I need to add the source view to the background view :/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by recreating a cell and adding it to the popover containerView:

```
- (void)prepareForPopoverPresentation:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {
    [[popoverPresentationController containerView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.72]];

    MessageCellNode *messageNode = [[MessageCellNode alloc] init];

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [[self.collectionNode view] layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPathToSelect];
    CGRect cellRect = attributes.frame;

    CGRect rect = [[[self collectionNode] view] convertRect:cellRect toView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [messageNode setFrame: rect];

    [[popoverPresentationController containerView]addSubview:[messageNode view]];
}
```

Result:
[image]